# web scraping same origin policy problem preventing access

Tags: jquery, json, same-origin-policy, stock

Trying to write a simple call to google's JSON stock ticker API. I would like to get JSON, however, the same origin policy comes up. Any ideas of how to work around this? I've heard of using an iFrame, but was hoping for something simpler or more elegant.

Here is my call:

```
$('#ticker').change(function() {
      url = "http://www.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=" + this.value;
      $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
          alert(data);
        });
});
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the data in your page before you serve it up. Make a server-to-server XMLHTTP call. Alternately there is JSONP:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: great. However, google puts a "//" in front of the JSON code so it returns an error. I guess it's psuedo-JSON.